# how to implement carousel in angular 2 when plugins are written in plain javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

i want to implement owlcarousel, simply including it in index.html not working.are any DefinitelyTyped files available for that.

Comment: anything you tried yet ?

Comment: I was trying to implement slick-slider. https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/slick-carousel/slick-carousel-tests.ts
but not sure how to use that.